# Using Pthread in Azure web app in a PHP site

Tags: php, multithreading, azure, pthreads

I have a webapp (PHP site using CodeIgniter) hosted on Azure. I have a situation where I want to use the pthread module. Since pthread is not available in PHP out of the box, when I install it using Xampp server, I suspect that it won't be possible to use threading on Azure.

But I am not sure. Azure documentation also doesn't talk about it. Is there a way I can use it pthread on Azure?

I am able to use it on my local Windows machine, using `pthread.dll`.

Comment: if you have a root level access then yes you can do it.

Comment: do you mean, the access to the php folder and php extension folder? Azure only gives me access to a webroot folder.

Comment: I mean ssh access to server. You may have to rebuild PHP with thread safety if it is not already. May be than you can install Pthread throuh pecl installer.

Comment: No i have just a webapp hosted on the azure. No virtual Machine

Comment: Why do you wish to use multi-threading? If you want to run tasks in the background, a job queue is much easier to deal with. What is your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable extension in Azure Web APP, we should customize PHP runtime on Azure. Please refer to [official site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-use-a-custom-php-runtime).

For this issue,I have tried to install `pthreads` successfully. And I toke those steps as following:

1, I obtained a `PHP 5.4 (5.4.43) VC9 x86 Thread Safe` package from [PHP site](http://windows.php.net/download/) explored to folder named PHP. And followed the [pthreads site](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads), got the lasted version of pthreads.

2,Added `pthreadVC2.dll` (included with the Windows releases) to the same directory as *`php.exe`* and added *`php_pthreads.dll`* to PHP extention folder.

3,I uesd `phpinfo()` to find default *`php.ini`* file in Azure, which should be similar with the picture:
[image],

Then I browsed Kudu Console of my web app via  *`https://<your_web_app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell`*.

Locate to the directory found above. Download the content to local saved as *`php.ini`* in the PHP directory. Uncommented `extension_dir = "ext"` in this file.

4, Add a bin directory to your root directory (for example, bin\php), and use FTP tool to upload the PHP runtime on it.

5,Browse to the web app in the Azure Portal and click the **configure** tab.
Add `*.php` to the Extension field and add the path to the `php-cgi.exe` executable at the **Handler mappings** section.[image]

At last, we check the PHP env,we should see the result as below
[image]

and run the test code of pthreads to check the extension

[image]

If you have any concern, please feel free to let me know.