# How to install php thread in azure platform

Tags: php, azure, pthreads

I am not able to install php thread in azure. as we can not modify most of the directories and php.ini files.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the steps in this answer [Using Pthread in Azure web app in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536254/using-pthread-in-azure-web-app-in-a-php-site) to install `pthreads` in Azure web app successfully with PHP 5.6 (5.6.29) VC11 x86 **Thread Safe** and pthreads version 2.0.9.

In which case, some additional modifications might be needed in step 3.

> 3, I used phpinfo() to find default php.ini file in Azure, Then I
>   browsed Kudu Console of my web app via
>   `https://<your_web_app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell`.
>   Locate the directory found above. Download the content to local saved
>   as php.ini in the PHP directory. Uncommented `extension_dir = "ext"`
>   in this file.

- Once you have downloaded the `php.ini` file, change
  `extension_dir="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\"` to
  `extension_dir = "ext"`.
- Add the line `extension=php_pthreads.dll` at the end of php.ini file.

Here the pictures:

[image]

I also tried to install pthreads v3 with PHP 7, but failed. Seems pthreads v3 is NOT supported by PHP-CGI, only by CLI version. The following statement is from [official site](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads).

> pthreads v3 is restricted to operating in CLI only: I have spent many
>   years trying to explain that threads in a web server just don't make
>   sense, after 1,111 commits to pthreads I have realised that, my advice
>   is going unheeded.
>
> So I'm promoting the advice to hard and fast fact: you can't use
>   pthreads safely and sensibly anywhere but CLI.
>
> Thanks for listening ;)

Hope this will help you. Any further concern, please let me know.